# Failed to load secured web map in leaflet map

Tags: proxy, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I set up and use proxy to load map from my ArcGIS Online organizational account. When I tried to load web map, error popped up ''esri/request: the first parameter should be a url string''.

Here is a script I used:

```
<script>
require([
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/core/urlUtils",
    "esri/WebMap",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
        MapView, urlUtils, WebMap
        ) {
        urlUtils.addProxyRule({
            urlPrefix: "http://my url/",
            proxyUrl: "/proxy.ashx/"
        });
        var webmap = new WebMap({
            portalItem: { 
                id: "web map id"
            }
        });
        var view = new MapView({
            map: webmap,
            container: "viewDiv"
        });
    });
</script>
```